# JWT web token Authorization validation give no data of claims

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

JWT tokken Validation give null
First I genrate the token , ant try to validate the token using Authorization handeler but in handle requirement async function all the claims are null.
In Which I genrate token

```
[Route("GenrateToken")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> GenerateJSONWebTokenAsync(mdlTookenRequest request )
    {
        
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        List<Claim> _claim = new List<Claim>();
        _claim.Add(new Claim("_CustomerId", request.CustomerId.ToString()));
        _claim.Add(new Claim("_UserId", request.UserId.ToString()));
        _claim.Add(new Claim("_CustomerType", ((int)request.customerType).ToString()));
        _claim.Add(new Claim("_Name", request.Name ??""));
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
            _config["Jwt:audience"],
          _claim,
          expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(_config["Jwt:tokenExpireinhour"])),
          signingCredentials: credentials);
        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
         
        
    }
```

but on validate all the claim give null values.

```
public class AccessRightRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public enmDocumentMaster accessRight;

    public AccessRightRequirement(enmDocumentMaster accessRight)
    {
        this.accessRight = accessRight;
    }
}
public class AccessRightHandler: AuthorizationHandler<AccessRightRequirement>
{
    private readonly ICurrentUsers _currentUser;
    public AccessRightHandler(ICurrentUsers currentUser)
    {
        _currentUser = currentUser;
    }
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AccessRightRequirement requirement)
    {
var data=context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "_UserId")?.Value;
if (data=="1")
           {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
}
```

My startup Config are this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
            };
        });
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            foreach (enmDocumentMaster _enm in Enum.GetValues(typeof(enmDocumentMaster)))
            {
                options.AddPolicy(_enm.ToString(), policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AccessRightRequirement(_enm)));
            }

        });
        services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, AccessRightHandler>();
        
        services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        services.AddScoped<IAccount>(ctx => new Account(ctx.GetRequiredService<DBContext>(), ctx.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>()));
       services.AddScoped<ICurrentUsers>(ctx => new CurrentUsers( ctx.GetRequiredService<DBContext>()));
        //services.AddScoped<ICurrentUsers>(ctx => new CurrentUsers(ctx.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>(), ctx.GetRequiredService<DBContext>()));

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "B2BApis", Version = "v1" });
        });

        
    }
```

[image]
PLease Tell me what is wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code to get the user from claims

```
public int? GetUserId()
{
            int? userId = null;
            var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
var userIdObj = identity == null ? null : 
identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "_UserId");
            if (userIdObj != null) userId = Convert.ToInt32(userIdObj.Value);
            return userId;
}
```

Comment: I also tried to get the data using HttpContext, But still It get the null values

Comment: @Prabhakar It means that you are not using the token. Can you show the code  you are uising to call the API, pls?

Comment: In my question I already mention , I Created a function that GenrateToken.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Check Your Token Authority i fix my problem with this way :

```
    services
         .AddAuthentication(option =>
         {
             option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
             option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

         })
        .AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            o.Authority = authority;
            o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
            o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidTypes = new[] { "at+jwt" };
            o.RequireHttpsMetadata = requireHttps;
            o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    var claims = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                    if (!claims.Claims.Any())
                        context.Fail("This token has no claims.");
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },

                OnChallenge = context =>
                {
                    if (context.AuthenticateFailure != null)
                        throw new AppException("Authenticate failure.", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                    throw new AppException("You are unauthorized to access this resource.", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                }
            };
        });
```